# How to set the first radio button as selected after filter applied?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have the following select list...

```
<select id="TicketTypeDropdown" data-ng-model="ticketSelection" class="railResultSelect">

                @foreach (var ticket in @Model.Fares.Select(a => a.Description).Distinct())
                {
                    <option>@ticket</option>
                }
            </select>
```

Which then sets a filter on a list of ticket options...

```
                 <ul>                      
                        <li class="ticketPriceListItem" data-ng-repeat="fare in model.Fares | filter:ticketSelection" data-ng-checked="$first">
                            <label>
                                <input type="radio" tabindex="0" data-ng-value="fare" data-ng-model="$parent.selectedTicket" />
                                {{fare.Description}} <span class="right">£{{fare.Price}}</span>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                </ul>
```

This all works fine. The problem I am having is I want the first radio button to always be selected. When the filter is applied the selected radio button disappears.

How can I always have the first option selected even after the filter is applied? Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

That may help you to solve your issue you encountered. You can declare a startup value in `$scope` or in `ng-init` for your condition -where you want-.
Do not forget to write your own condition:

```
<input type="radio" tabindex="0" data-ng-value="fare" data-ng-model="$parent.selectedTicket" selected="{{someCondition ? 'selected' : '' }}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-init`

```
ng-init="$index==$first?$parent.selectedTicket=fare:null"
```